# Angular material 2 : mat-optgroup inside mat-autocomplete

Tags: angular, typescript, autocomplete, dropdown, angular-material2

My goal is to obtain a dropdown  with autocomplete in Angular + Angular Material, but this dropwon contains group.

Like this :

```
Input : "d" <---------- autocomplete
   [D <------------------- group
     Dog <------------- option1
     Dragon <---------- option2
    ...
   ]
```

Here is a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nwdj9u) with :

- simple dropdown + autocomplete  => Working
- dropdown containing groups + autocomplete => **Help needed**

Thanks for your help !

ps : related to issue => [Example about mat-optgroup inside mat-autocomplete #10196](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/10196)

Comment: Result here after documentation update : [#10666](https://github.com/angular/material2/pull/10666)